# Infinite Taylor series and Taylor's Theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

The Taylor series for $e^x$ at $0$ is $1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + \cdots$. I understand that Taylor's theorem tells us we can make this series finite and get a reasonable approximation for $e^x$ when $x$ is close to $0$. But why does the infinite sum still work for any value of $x$? for example $e^{50} = 1 + 50 + 50^2/2! + \cdots$ even though $50$ is not "near" $0$?

I guess another way of asking my question is: we say that the Taylor series for $e^x$ at $0$ is $1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + \cdots$. But why can we write $e^x=1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + \cdots$ without any referrence to the "about $a$" part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it can be shown that the series you mention converges to $e^x$ for any value of $x$. This is due to Taylor's Theorem, which says that 
$$
 e^x-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}= \frac{e^{\xi}\,x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},
$$
for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$. Then, since $e<3$,
$$
\left| e^{50}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{{50}^k}{k!}\right|\leq \frac{3^{50}\,50^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.
$$
Choosing $n$ big enough, you can make the right-hand-side above less than any positive number you want, so the approximation will be as good as you want it.

Comment: So generalizing away from $e^x$, we can always write $f(x) = S(x)$ where $S(x)$ is the Taylor's series for $f(x)$ at $0$ (assuming $f$ has all the nice properties)? What I'm having trouble with seeing is: is there something about taking the series "about 0"? For example, the Taylor series for $e^x$ about $1$ is $e^1 + e^1(x-1) + e^1(x-1)^2/2!+\cdots$, but can we also say $e^x = e^1 + e^1(x-1) + e^1(x-1)^2/2!+\cdots$?

Comment: You can also write the series of the exponential at $1$; it is less interesting, though, because the coefficients depend on $e$ (which is trascendental) as opposed to just quotients of integers. For arbitrary functions, the series does not necessarily represent the function, even if it converges. It does, when/where the remainder of the Taylor polynomial converges to zero (for many functions, it doesn't).